# Generalizable function to select and filter dataframe r - using shiny input

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny

I am building a shiny app. The user will need to be able to reduce the data by selecting variables and filtering on specific values for those variables. I am stuck trying to get a generalizable function that can work based on all possible selections.

Here is an example - I skip the shiny code because I think the problem is with the function:

```
#sample dataframe
df <- data.frame('date' = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1), 
                 'time' = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'b', 'a', 'e'), 
                 'place' = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'H', 'A', 'H', 'H'), 
                 'result' = c('W', 'W', 'L', 'W', 'W', 'L', 'L'))
```

If the user selected `date` and `result` for the `date values 1, 2`; and the `result values W`, I would do the following:

```
out <- df %>%
    select(date, result) %>%
    filter(date %in% c(1,2)) %>%
    filter(result %in% c('W'))
```

The challenge I am having is that the user can select any unique combinations of variables and values. Using the `input$` values from my shiny app, I can get the selected variables into a vector and I can get the selected values into a list of values, positionaly matching the selected variables. For example:

```
selected_variables <- c('date', 'result')
selected_values <- list(c(1,2), c('W'))
```

What i think i then need is a generalizable function that will match up the filter calls with the correct variables. Something like:

```
#function that takes data frame, vector of selected variables, list of vectors of chosen values for each variable
#Returns a reduced table of selected variables, filtered values
table_reducer <- function(df, select_var, filter_values) { 
    #select the variables        
    out <- df %>%
    #now filter each variable by the values contained in the list
    select(vect_of_var)
    out <- [for loop that iterates over vect_of_var, list_of_vec, filtering accordingly]
    out #return out
}
```

My thinking would be to use a `zip` equivalent from python, but all my searching on that just points me to `mapply` and i can't see how to use that within the for loop (which i also know is not always approved in R - but i am talking about a relatively small number of iterations). If there is a better solution to this i would welcome it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a 1-liner `table_reducer` function in base R -

```
table_reducer <- function(df, select_var, filter_values) {
  subset(df, Reduce(`&`, Map(`%in%`, df[select_var], filter_values)))  
}

selected_variables <- c('date', 'result')
selected_values <- list(c(1,2), c('W'))
table_reducer(df, selected_variables, selected_values)

#  date time place result
#1    1    a     A      W
#2    2    b     A      W
#4    2    e     H      W
#5    2    b     A      W
```

`Map` is a wrapper over `mapply` so you were right in thinking that you should use `mapply` for this task. This answer is also free of dreaded `for` loops.

Comment: Works well. Thanks.